# Terracotta bigmemory-max client

Tags: distributed-caching, terracotta, ehcache-bigmemory

In a multi stripes distributed cache cluster:
1. How does client requests are balanced between different stripes?
2. Does client fetch/put data only from/to one stripe (which internally might remotely forward the request to another stripe's active server according to the location of the partitioned data)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. The striping is based on sharding data. So requests go to the stripe that holds the data for a given key.
2. Clients know about cluster topology and direct requests to the correct stripe based on the data key.

[Product documentation](http://www.terracotta.org/documentation/)